# Web scraping IMDB with Python's Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

I am trying to parse this page "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068112/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1", but I can't find the `href` that I need (`href="/title/tt0068112/episodes?ref_=tt_eps_sm"`).

I tried with this code:

```
url="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068112/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1"
page(requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(a['href'])
```

What's wrong with this? I also tried to check "manually" with `print(soup.prettify())` but it seems that that link is hidden or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the page html with requests, the `href` item is in there, no need for special apis. I tried this and it worked:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
page = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068112/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    
scooby_link = ""
for item in soup.findAll("a", href="/title/tt0068112/episodes?ref_=tt_eps_sm"):
    print(item["href"])
    scooby_link = "https://www.imdb.com" + "/title/tt0068112/episodes?ref_=tt_eps_sm"
    
print(scooby_link)
```

I'm assuming you also wanted to save the link to a variable for further scraping so I did that as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The fact is that I want to be able to find it without specifying the entire link, but just with some key word (in that case with the title code). I need some general rule because I have to do multiple searches through that site. Furthermore once I reach one of those link (like the one that I post) I have to find links for each episodes and I'm finding the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get the link with `Episodes` you can use next example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068112/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
print(soup.select_one("a:-soup-contains(Episodes)")["href"])
```

Prints:

```
/title/tt0068112/episodes?ref_=tt_eps_sm
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The fact is that I want to be able to find it without specifying the entire link, but just with some key word (in that case with the title code). I need some general rule because I have to do multiple searches through that site. Furthermore once I reach one of those link (like the one that I post) I have to find links for each episodes and I'm finding the same problem.